# Extract Frames From a Video?

Tags: node.js

I want to extract frames from a Video and save the frames

```
var express = require("express"),

 var video = "./s/video.mp4";
 var storeOutput = "./store"
 function getVideoFrames(){
        // get frames
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally, when it comes to work with video, *ffmpeg* is a great tool to use.
There is a [ffmpeg-extract-frames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-extract-frames) package on the npm repository, based on *fluent-ffmpeg*, that perform exactly that.

```
const extractFrames = require('ffmpeg-extract-frames')

extractFrames({
  input: 's/video.mp4',
  output: './store/frame-%d.jpg'
})
```

If you need, you can pass an array of time, in milliseconds, to the `offsets` option to extract only specific frames.

```
extractFrames({
  input: 's/video.mp4',
  output: './store/screenshot-%i.jpg',
  offsets: [
    1000,
    2000,
    3000
  ]
})
```